# How to add a close button to alertify log with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alertify

I'm trying to add this close button to my [alertify log message](https://alertifyjs.org/). The final display should be something like this:

[image: log message wit close button]

I've tried a few solutions listed on SO but for some reason I'm not able to move the close button out of the `alertify log` message. The overflow for the close button is always hidden, and I've tried playing with the CSS settings but it is not working.

```js
var fn = function() {
  alertify.log('How to add close button? <a href="" class="close-icon"></a>');
};

fn();
```

```css
.close-icon
{
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right:-5px;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
    background-color:black;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/master/dist/css/alertify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/master/dist/js/alertify.js"></script>
<button onclick="fn();">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Test</span>
</button>
```

Comment: How are you adding that close-icon class to the alertify logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the content overflows out of the container and that content is hidden. An easy way to fix this is with:

```
.alertify-logs > div {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```js
var fn = function() {
  alertify.log('How to add close button? <a href="" class="close-icon"></a>');
};

fn();
```

```css
.close-icon
{
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right:-5px;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-radius:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%,  white 56%,transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
    background-color:black;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.alertify-logs > div {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/master/dist/css/alertify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/master/dist/js/alertify.js"></script>
<button onclick="fn();">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Test</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! that seems to make it work! Have one question though.. Alertify is pretty deeply integrated into our project and though I can paste this in our site.css, do you think there can be any unforeseeable effects of doing this.. To re-phrase my question, Is there a way to make this CSS apply to only log messages with the close-button only?

Comment: @supersan Good question. CSS doesn't have parent selectors so that makes it a little tricky. Off the top of my head I can't think of a way but I'm certain there is one.